# powershell confused about array loop, foreach method, string?

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to export all CA certificates to a directory in Base64 format, I'm new to powershell, since I'm used to doing scripts with bash.  Somehow I'm not seeing something that feels like it should be obvious.

This is my line so far,

```
@(Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\Localmachine\ca).ForEach({Export-Certificate -Type CERT -FilePath "C:\ssl\certs.d\$_.Thumbprint" -Cert "Cert:\LocalMachine\ca\$_.Thumbprint"})
```

I appreciate any help, as I'm trying to learn how to be idiomatic in PS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code contains 3 issues:

**First. String interpolation with object property.** PS parser doesn't understand `"$var.Property"`, it only understands `$expression` within "string". But since it's expression, and not just variable name, you can make PS evaluate your line with `"$(something to evaluate)"`. In other words, your `-FilePath` should be:

```
-FilePath "C:\ssl\certs.d\$($_.Thumbprint)"
```

**Second. Working with objects.** PS underneath is full-blown .Net Framework. Even though many objects are represented in output in a simple, predefined way, actually they are |ed to output as complete live objects. According to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848628.aspx), the `-Cert` parameter is a `<Certificate>`, not a string pointing to a certificate, so your `-Cert` should be simply

```
-Cert $_
```

**Third. Arrays.** `Get-ChildItem` underneath is nothing more than [DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/806sc8c5(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns an array of objects. So ideally, you don't need to wrap it with anything and it's possible to simply pipe it further (`Get-ChildItem | Foreach-Object{...}`). But many people have different tastes on PS syntax, so the form of `(gci).ForEach({...})` (without @) has the right to live as well. But what you are doing in form of `@(...)` is **creating a new array** of one item being the array returned to you by `gci`. So technically, it just shouldn't work. It will though, because PS saves you from such mistakes automatically: in PS you can work with array of 1 item in the same way as with this item directly (unless explicitly specified opposite). To illustrate,

```
@(4).Length # returns 1
@(@(2,3)).Length # returns 2
@(,@(2,3)).Length #returns 1
```

Thus, your current syntax for `Get-ChildItem` is error-prone and relies on automatic PS error-handling sugar. I recommend to either remove `@` in the beginning, or to rewrite in form of

```
Get-ChildItem -...... | Foreach-Object {...}
```

Comment: _"`@(...)` is creating a new array of one item being the array returned to you by gci"_ - Nope, If the output is already an array then the use of an array subexpession will have no affect on the output. Example: `@(@(1))[0].GetType()` - returns `Int32`, not `Object[]`.

Comment: It's not because the item is array; it;s because the super-array contains 1 item. If what you say was true and limited to what you say - then your example would result in `System.Array` not `System.Int32`. I explained the behavior by those 3 examples.